# How may I test a .service (systemd) file, from its dev path, before putting it in /etc/systemd/system?

Tags: systemd, services

I have created a service file, but it's my first one.

I wonder what could happen if I was to put a badly written service into `/etc/systemd/system` directory.
Might my system not reboot, next time?

...I'd like to test it before putting it there.

```
[Unit]
Description=ecoemploi backend métier
After=network-online.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=%i
Restart=no

ExecStart=/home/lebihan/dev/Java/comptes-france/metier-et-gestion/ApplicationMetierEtGestion/java \
    --add-exports java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED \
    --add-opens java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED \
    --add-opens java.base/java.nio=ALL-UNNAMED \
    --add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED \
    --add-opens java.base/java.lang.invoke=ALL-UNNAMED \
    -jar target/application-metier-et-gestion.jar

# Configures the time to wait before service is stopped forcefully.
TimeoutStopSec=300

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I haven't found an option with `systemctl` to launch my `ecoemploi-back-metier.service` from its current dev directory, instead of searching it inside its `/etc/systemd/service` path.

What's the way to do the test I'm willing to do?

Comment: If you don't enable it, nothing will happen from it being in the service folder

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just place them in `/etc/systemd/system`; unit files placed there *do not* automatically become part of the boot process – that only happens once they are "installed" into e.g. multi-user.target using `systemctl enable`.

You can put your custom units there and manually `systemctl start` them, *without* "enabling" the unit to start on boot.

In general, a unit that simply fails to start will not break the boot process, unless you make some other important units depend on it. And if you do that, you can use the `systemd.mask=` boot option (kernel command-line option) to make systemd ignore specific units for a single boot.

If you want to be safe, you can place units in `/run/systemd/system`, an in-memory location which will not persist across reboots.